# Will Vert.x pose a threat to Node.js's user base due to it's much better performance?

Tags: node.js, vert.x

[Benchmark](http://vertxproject.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/vert-x-vs-node-js-simple-http-benchmarks/)

[Hacker News Discussion](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3948727)

[Hacker News Discussion 2](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3927891)

Comment: Can you phrase your description a bit better?

Comment: No.. Benchmark : http://nodejx.com/nodejx-vs-vert-x-vs-node-js-cluster/

Answer (score 6):

It's not like Node.js is even really dominant today (except in the Hacker News community of course), it hasn't even had a 1.0 release yet.  Funny to be speculating on what might replace it already :)

Performance is nice (though micro-benchmarks are not the right way to judge that) but if that was the only thing that mattered we would all be writing custom web servers in C for every app. One of the other important things is the community support, which Node.js definitely has going for it at the moment. It has a very healthy open source (this being the key) community that has created a large library of tools.

I think Vert.x is interesting and has a different way of looking at things than Node.js which is great.  If they are able to continue to make progress, get more people interested in it, and show that it is easier and faster to write web apps then who knows? Maybe in a few years we can have a discussion on what is going to threaten Vert.x's future.

Comment: and it still hasn't had a 1.0 release......... yup still waiting nearly 3 years on!

Comment: Everybody has pretty much moved over to io.js now which just had a 2.0 release.  Turns out it wasn't vert.x but a fork of Node that replaced Node.

Comment: Not easy to make that switchover for a big corporation though - technically io.js is a fork and not officially supported. There's a lot of uncertainty created by disputes such as this and it doesn't give a great impression of the community when there's battling at the top.

Comment: So many things changed 9 years later, guys :v

Answer (score 3):

There are some interesting things brought up by this micro-benchmark that may be worth addressing in Node, but it's very important to remember that nobody doing 100's of millions of hits per day (which these benchmarks show) does so on one machine. They do it on many machines.

There are certain levels where faster languages make a difference (see for example Twitter migrating their backend from Ruby to Java), but it's VERY rare to get to that position.

Most people need a language that is clean and easy to program in, and a good ecosystem.

Vert.x has no ecosystem to speak of. If you want a JVM based system you can get plenty of options there. If you want a Javascript based system the best option right now is Node.js. It's that simple.

Comment: Vert.x might not have an ecosystem currently, but it's just a matter of time.

Comment: I dont think so. Node.js was first and already has a huge user base. No node.js developer swaps to vert.x because a few microbenchmark done by the vert.x developers show better results in a totally unrealistic scenario. I could easily write a small C server which beats the hell out of vert.x but who wants to write assynchronous servers in C (or Java - wait, no closures :D ?) It all comes down to the ecosystem and vert.x still does not have a community besides the core developers.

Comment: And polyglot is not really attractive. Python devs will use gevent or twisted, ruby devs use eventmachine and javascript devs use node.js. So the whole "polyglot" story is nonsense. It is really just interesting for the JVM world. And in the Java world there are already very nice frameworks all with a more active community as vert.x, period.

Comment: Vert.x inherits Java's ecosystem, which is way more complete than Node.js. Moreover, the [worker verticles](http://vertx.io/manual.html#writing-blocking-code-introducing-worker-verticles) makes it possible to integrate safely all the libraries that involve "blocking" code.

Comment: Polyglot does become important when writing distributed apps.